# PHP Session not functioning

Tags: php, linux, session

A YUM update was ran on the server of one of my clients yesterday and suddenly all session-functionality has stopped working. I've brought it down to the absolute basics and I can't figure out why it's not working. I have these two files:

File1.php

```
<?php
session_start();

echo "Session ID: " . session_id();

$abbo = "freemium";

$_SESSION['abbo'] = $abbo;

echo "abbo: ".$_SESSION['abbo']."";

exit;

?>
```

File2.php

```
<?php
session_start();

echo "Session ID: " . session_id();

echo "abbo: ".$_SESSION['abbo']."";

?>
```

Both are in the ROOT directory of the domain. Both files dispaly the same session_id so the session actually exists. However, the second page doesn't display the variable, where the first one does. What's going wrong?

Comment: Obvious checks: verify if the sessions cookie is stored or changes, verify what the session directory is and whether files are being created.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, does the fact that both pages display the same session_id not confirm that the files are being created?

Comment: Worked fine for me. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii-, following error popped up: Warning: Unknown: open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_65s5es092osat71cob8d32ab15, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0 Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/session) in Unknown on line 0. So it's a permissions issue?

Comment: You're welcome. I tend to think so, yes. Check the folder's permissions settings.

Comment: @user2704687 - Your last comment proves it doesn't. Anyway, the "no need to check" approach is fine when things do work ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, thanks, going to try to resolve that!

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, you are exactly right. Thanks a lot!